# WPF: Is there a way to use PrintDialog only to select the target printer without having to provide a DocumentPaginator class?

Tags: wpf, printing, documentpaginator

I want to print a very simple layout with `PrintDocument` that fits on one page, so it doesn't require a `DocumentPaginator`. However I want to use `PrinterDialog` to select the printer. I saw examples with `PrinterSettings` being a property of `PrinterDialog` and it was simply assigned to the `PrintDocument`. But this doesn't seem to be possible anymore. I also looked for other solutions like custom paginator classes to use but came up empty. I might not have this deep insight into WPF, but why must it always be dongled that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

- Import `System.Printing`
- Create a `PrintDialog`

And then:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), "PrinterName");
printDialog.PrintDocument(document, "PrintDocument");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointig me to PrintQueue. With printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printDialog.PrintQueue.FullName, I only hope the Name is compatible in every case...